# How to check if Windows is embedded or POS?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++

I am developing a program that I do not want to be installed on embedded versions of windows. Is there an API call I can make or some standard way of detecting if the current windows version is embedded/pos?

Comment: Why would you care? If it's an unsupported configuration, then it's unsupported. If it blows up, tough. That's the user's problem. If it's not a technical reason, then let's just say code is a poor mechanism for enforcing licensing requirements…

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, this helps. You have to use the OSVERSIONINFOEX struct and check the wSuiteMask member...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724833%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: A good start, but the documentation suggests that `VER_SUITE_EMBEDDEDNT` only identifies Windows XP Embedded. What about other versions? There are embedded versions of Vista, 7, and 8—at least.

Comment: @Cody Gary: I do not have all the windows versions to test, maybe it is a documentation typo. AFAIK XP, Vista, 7 and 8 are all NT class windows versions, right ?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the Windows Management Instrumentation classes.  In particular, you should be able to get what you want from the [Win32_OperatingSystem class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394239(v=vs.85).aspx) object and its various member elements.  It provides a bit more information than the OSVERSIONINFOEX structure.